# How to solve the error "'cypress' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Tags: cypress

I have updated the cypress version from 3.1.3 to 3.1.4 and after that when ever I am running the npm run cypress:open command, it is throwing error "'cypress' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! xxxxx@1.0.0 cypress:open: `cypress open --env aaa=test`
npm ERR! Exit status 1"

Any advice, how to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you check there's `cypress`/`cypress.bat` in your `<project>/node_modules/.bin` folder? If not, try uninstalling and installing the cypress anew.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, at last uninstalling and installing again worked fine.

Answer (score 14):

You need to be running:

```
npx cypress open
```

to open it.

Comment: Doesn't work: Error: Cannot find module '~\npm\node_modules\cypress\bin\cypress' No idea why it's looking in bin instead of .bin. Or why it's looking in ~\npm instead of .\node_modules.

Answer (score 1):

if you installed cypress locally in your project, you need to run your command from `node_modules/.bin`, for example `./node_modules/.bin/cypress run` if you want to run `cypress run` or just run `npx cypress run` that just do the same

Answer (score 0):

I just installed it again by executing

```
npm install cypress --save-dev
```

And then when running it again it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I installed it again by executing

```
npm install cypress --save-dev
```

and then running using below command and it worked

```
\\node_modules\.bin\cypress open
```